# CollectionView. Maximum distance between Item. Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I know there is only minimum spacing between items and you can achieve that via size inspector or

`func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets`

Indeed on the simulator on SE my items are shown like in the image below.
[image]

But when I run on a larger simulator my distance between cell items is increasing and aren t showing as expected.

Is there any method to set like a maximum size between them ?

Comment: So, you want to let the space between them is to be always zero points?

Comment: like 5 x pts or something like that.

Comment: you should provide cell width too. space between is not really a property. It will change according to cell width. Calculate cell widths according to the current screen size .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logically, there is another factor that you should keep in mind for setting the space between the items in your collection view, which is the *size* of the cell. If you are getting the cell as is (with its default size) -and my assumption is that's your case-, it would be statically dequeued in the collection view, i.e the size of the cell would be as is.

So, what you should do is to tell what is the desired size (width) of the cells to be displayed in the collection view, by conforming to
 [`UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdelegateflowlayout) and implementing [`collectionView(_:layout:sizeForItemAt:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdelegateflowlayout/1617708-collectionview):

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    // let's assume that each row in the collection view should contains 3 cells:
    let desiredWidth = collectionView.frame.width / 3

    // height is also equals to the width to be a square...
    return CGSize(width: desiredWidth, height: desiredWidth)
}
```

At this point if you are setting the minimum space between items to zero, each row should contains three cells with no space between them.

If you are aiming to set a little space between the cells, you should reflect it when declaring the desired width for the cell, for example:

```
// since each row contains 3 cells, subtracting 2 from each cell width
// means it would be 6 points (3 * 2) divided at the whole row (2 spaces, 3 points for each)
let desiredWidth = collectionView.frame.width / 3 - 2
```

Comment: well actually I m calling '    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {


            return CGSize(width: 100, height: 280)
    }'

Comment: What you said above it helps me . it does. But what if i want the exact width?

Comment: actually my cell item width is expanding depeding on the device

Comment: @FagadariuMarcel if I didn't got it wrong, if the cell width should be always as is regardless of what's the size of the device screen, there is no doubt it would be spaces between the cells :)

Comment: Ok , i Did as u said but i want also  to return UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 5, bottom: 10, right: 5)...right and left  for a little spacing so my cells aren 't stick to the device layout.. now it only shows me 2 cells

Comment: @FagadariuMarcel then try to decrease the value of `desiredWidth`, thus I think you'll get the desired output.